# Typesetting an expression in bold in an equation environment

Tags: math-mode, boldmath

I would like to typeset an expression involving limits in bold font.  The code I have typesets only some of the characters in bold font. Those letters in bold are not in italics, though.

```
\documentclass[10pt]{amsart}
\usepackage{mathtools}



\begin{document}

\noindent
\begin{minipage}{5.75in}
{\em A sequence $(a_{n})_{\scriptscriptstyle{n=1}}^{\scriptscriptstyle{\infty}}$ \textbf{diverges to \boldmath$\infty$\unboldmath} if, and only if, for every $M > 0$, there is a big enough positive integer $N$ so that for every integer $n \geq N$, $a_{n} > M$.}
{\boldmath
\begin{equation*}
\mathbf{\displaystyle{\lim_{n\to\infty} a_{n} = \infty}}
\end{equation*}
}
{\em denotes the condition that $(a_{n})_{\scriptscriptstyle{n=1}}^{\scriptscriptstyle{\infty}}$ diverges to $\infty$.}
\end{minipage}

\end{document}
```

Comment: One should be careful changing fonts in math because that can change the meaning of symbols. If you just want to emphasize the equation, consider the `empheq` package in the `mathtools` bundle. If it must be bold, `\bm{...}` will embolden most symbols.

Comment: `\mathbf` produces the roman font and `\displaystyle` isn't doing anything in `equation` which is displaystyle already

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you want only part of an equation you want bold, use the `\bm` package. For a whole equation, I defined a `boldeqn*` which is `\boldmath` followed by an `equation*` environment:

```
\documentclass{amsart}
\usepackage{mathtools}
\usepackage{bm}

\newenvironment{boldeqn*}{\boldmath\begin{equation*}}{\end{equation*}\ignorespacesafterend}

\begin{document}

\noindent A sequence $(a_{n})_{n=1}^{\infty}$ diverges to $\infty$ if, and only if, for every $M > 0$, there is a big enough positive integer $N$ so that for every integer $n \geq N$, $a_{n} > M$.

\begin{boldeqn*}
\lim_{n\to\infty} a_{n} = \infty
\end{boldeqn*}

\begin{equation*}
\bm{\lim_{n\to\infty} a_{n} = \infty} \qquad \lim_{n\to\infty}b_{n} = 0
 \end{equation*}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: I coded `\boldmath\begin{equation*} \lim_{n\to\infty} a_{n} = \infty \end{equation*}\unboldmath`.  It typeset the expression in bold, but the `a` and `n` were not typeset in italics.

Comment: I would like to avoid putting a `\newenvironment` command in the preamble.  Please keep it in your response, though.

Comment: In this case, just use `{\boldmath\begin{equation*} .... \end{equation*}}`.

Comment: @David Carlisle: Thanks for the addition! I already met the  problem, but had completely forgotten.

Comment: I made the edit you suggested.  I get the `a` and `n` in `a_{n}` and the `n` under the limit operator typeset in the same font as the font in text mode.

Comment: I don't have the same result. Could you post the exact code you used?

Comment: @Adelyn do you get the text font using exactly the file as Bernard posts here? If so there is something odd with your tex installation.

Comment: @Bernard  I just edited the code.  What I had posted was originally in a `minipage` environment.

Comment: @Adelyn: If you switch to `\boldmath`, don't use `\mathbf`: it uses `\textbf` (bold upright, not italic). Also, you don't have to use `\unboldmath`, sinece `\boldmath` is  set inside a group.

Comment: @Bernard  You can see from my post that I did use `\boldmath` preceding the `equation` environment.   Letters were typeset in bold of the default font of `amsart`.  Why does my code give a different display than your code?

Comment: You have a and n in `upright` boldface, don't you?

Comment: @Bernard  I want them in italics.

Comment: Well, remove `\mathbf`: `\boldmath`does the job.